# Stop an iterator at an index

Tags: java, iterator

I am trying to stop an iterator at a certain index.

Example, I start off with ABCDEF and if I type iterator(3), I only want it to return ABC and not the rest.
Below is what I have tried doing.

```
if(stop>this.size() ){ 
   throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(); 
}
Iterator<E> iterator = iterator();
int  i = 0 ; 

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    if(i<stop){
        iterator.next();
        i++;
    }
    else{
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  As it is, your code is useless - there's no way it could work.

Comment: If you can use Guava, `Iterators.limit(iterator(), stop)`.

Comment: So, what is the problem? (Other than the fact that you're not keeping the value of `iterator.next()` anywhere)?

Comment: What you show so far looks workable with some cleanup. There are a few loop idioms available but that gets into maintainability decisions more than logic. What is your issue? I agree with @betseyb that we need a complete runnable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my way to do it. Because I think op suggest the stop is the end of the loop.

```
if(stop>this.size() ){
throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
}
else
{
Iterator<E> iterator = iterator();

for (int j = 0; j <stop ; j++) {
    if(iterator.hasNext()){
     // Todo
     }else {
         break;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do your stuff like below code with `for` loop:

```
if(stop>this.size() ){
throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
}
Iterator<E> iterator = iterator();
int  i = 0 ;

for (int j = 0; j <3 ; j++) {
if(iterator.hasNext()){
//do what you want here loop itrate only three times
}else {
        i=j;
         break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use both `i` and `j`? Why set `i` to `j` at the end?

Comment: in above query @jjk hold value of `i` and in my case if iterator does not have three or more element value i have actual number of iterations .

Comment: Well, OP didn't specify that the actual number of iteration is needed anywhere. Just that there should be no more than three.

Comment: if @jik does not want to take value of `i`  he can understand and skip else part. :)

Comment: my problem is I'm not sure what i want to do, it's just a method, I'm not sure how long it is what are the keys etc, like i thought i have to return iterator if it hasNext.... but that just  return ABCDE...